In python, is there a way or tool to handle odd numbers root? like root3 root5 root7
i try to create a program that equal two equation, for an example: (X^2 = X, X will be 0,1)
but i have problem with scenario that equation is odd number root like root3 root5 root7...
beacuse when i print((-1)**(1/3)) in thonny i got (0.5000000000000001+0.8660254037844386j) when it should be -1
and that the problem, when equation is like X^3 = X^(1/3), it only return X as [0,1] when it should be [-1,0,1]
here my code:
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, integrate
X = symbols('X')
m = input('Y1 equation (use ^ as power, use x as multiply (Y and X must be big text)): ').replace('^', '**').replace('x', '*')
n = input('Y2 equation (use ^ as power, use x as multiply (Y and X must be big text)): ').replace('^', '\*\*').replace('x', '*')
a, b = m.split('=')
c, d = n.split('=')
y1 = eval(b)
y2 = eval(d)
intersection_points = solve(Eq(y1, y2), X)
print(intersection_points)

so try to use sympy but it didn't work too, is there any library or medthod to handle this?

The expression (-1)**(1/3) is treated as one that generates a complex number. So the result you see is correct.

you can verify in wolfram alpha that the result is correct

but mathematical's wise it should be -1 isn't> how do i do it?

Your problem with sympy, is that Python converts "1/3" to a float. You can try to use sympy's sympify() on your strings instead of Python's eval(). from sympy import sympify; print((-1)**sympify("1/3")) will keep 1/3 in fraction form instead of converting it to a float.  See also sympy's gotchas

Generally in maths, a negative number raised to a non-integer power will be complex.
There are very precise fractions where one of the answers is a real number. Including your (-1)^(1/3), which has the real answer of -1, and 2 complex answers), but any error discrepancy from the fraction and you move into the complex plane.
When you solve (-1)**(1/3), the fraction is converted to floating point numbers first, and you are actually solving something like (-1)**(3.33......). Not being the precise fraction with a real answer this has 3 complex answers. One of these is reported to you.
To be sure that -1 remains an answer you need to ensure the fraction remains 1/3. Sympy can do this for you
from sympy import Rational
(-1)**Rational(1, 3)

this does give the perfect cube root of -1.
However note that the cube root of -1 does analytically have 3 answers,
-1
1/2+√3/2 
1/2-√3/2 

So any/all of these may be reported if you ask for one answer to be printed.

What you want can be done by explicitely handling odd roots of negative numbers:
def root(n, rank):
    if n < 0 and rank%2 == 1:
        return - root(-n, rank)
    return n**(1/rank)

It gives as expected:
root(8,3)
2.0
root(-8, 3)
-2.0
root(-1, 3)
-1.0

